# QTP(UFT) Vrs Coded-UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests, qtp, hp-uft

Hi im in the process of investigation other automation tools available on the street.  Currently i have a automation suite that uses the QC QTP stack, with the wpf plugin to hook into our desktop application.

In QTP this give me the opportunity to call the underlying object methods i.e WpfObject("MyCustomView").Object.DataContex.ClearMyViewCommand etc.  We can do this accross the entire application for majority of the controls.

For Coded ui is there a similar process?  It appears when i find the object specified i am only able to get the basic object properties and none of the customer underlying methods.  Ive investigate the NativeElement and majority of other methods for alot of the other controls but havnt been able to accomplish the same events.

Would anyone have any idea if this is possbible in Coded-UI?

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI uses accessibility to expose properties and methods to the test runner. This means that unless specific properties and methods have been exposed they are simply not available to Coded UI.

In your situation Coded UI could be used, but I don't think it should be used unless you have a lot of time on your hands.

You would essentially need to replace MSAA, with a custom technology and then expose the custom properties and methods using that technology.

Huge amount of development effort to get what you already have with QTP.